# Can you explain what if i am getting the loss added with scientific notation?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Epoch 100/100
4/4 [==============================] - 4s 968ms/step - loss: 1.4615e-07 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0154 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

> If i train my model with different parameters i am not having the loss like this. How to consider if i get loss like this?

> Please explain. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the question, but I will assume it has to do with the way the loss is displayed. It is normal for some values (under a certain threshold) to turn to scientific notation (with e). In your case, the loss is 0.00000014615 which is super small and thus it is converted to scientific notation. The other results for other parameters may differ because they are probably over the threshold needed for scientific notation.
A loss that small is good as long as it is obtained while making predictions on the validation / test set. If it is super low on training set, but it doesn't do as well on the validation / test sets then it might be the case that your model is overfitting.